# Creating an Arrylist in a Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my first post so sorry if I mess something up or if I am not clear enough. I have been looking through online forums for several hours and spend more trying to figure it out for myself.

I am reading information from a file and I need a loop that creates an ArrayList every time it goes through.

```
static ArrayList<String> fileToArrayList(String infoFromFile)
{
    ArrayList<String> smallerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    //This ArrayList needs to be different every time so that I can add them 
    //all to the same ArrayList

    if (infoFromFile != null) 
    {
        String[] splitData = infoFromFile.split(":");

        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) 
        {
            if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) 
            {
                smallerArray.add(splitData[i].trim());
            }

        }
    }
```

The reason I need to do this is that I am creating an app for a school project that reads questions from a delimited text file. I have a loop earlier that reads one line at a time from the text. I will insert that string into this program.

How do I make the ArrayList smallerArray a separate ArrayList everytime it goes through this method?

I need this so I can have an ArrayList of each of these ArrayList

Comment: `splitData[i] == null` is not necessary. It's never `null`. Besides, what's the actual question? There are no question marks in your *question*.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Add that makes the condition always verified. It should be modified to test the right condition.

Comment: You talk about reading a file, yet I see no file access in your example

Comment: You also can do a list of lists -> `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfSmallerLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code of what you intend to do -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SimpleFileReader {
    private static final String DELEMETER = ":";
    private String filename = null;

    public SimpleFileReader() {
        super();
    }

    public SimpleFileReader(String filename) {
        super();
        setFilename(filename);
    }   

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getRowSet() throws IOException {
        List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            stream.forEach(row -> rows.add(Arrays.asList(row.split(DELEMETER))));
        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

And, here is the JUnit test for the above code -

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SimpleFileReaderTest {
    public SimpleFileReaderTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFileReader() {

        try {
            SimpleFileReader reader = new SimpleFileReader("c:/temp/sample-input.txt");
            List<List<String>> rows = reader.getRowSet();

            int expectedValue = 3; // number of actual lines in the sample file
            int actualValue = rows.size(); // number of rows in the list

            if (actualValue != expectedValue) {
                fail(String.format("Expected value for the row count is %d, whereas obtained value is %d", expectedValue, actualValue));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```